# Android actionbar gradient glitch

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My app actionbar has a gradient as background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/black"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:angle="-90"/>
</shape>
```

It is applied to some activities programmatically using `actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_black_gradient));`

The problem is that some times, when I run the app (even without changing the binary), the actionbar shows a dark contour (see image). It happens both in my Nexus 7 (2012) and in the emulator, and it seems to only happen with API 21.

Does any one else ever seen something like that? Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the shadow of the Action Bar. You can remove it by using this line of code.

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```